# How to fix json dserialization using the api call

Tags: json, .net-core, blazor

I am having some issue to deserialize the json from an API

I have tried HTTP Client and rest sharp both as well

```
   @page "/Demographics"
@using System
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Diagnostics
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@using System.Threading.Tasks
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Newtonsoft.Json   
@inject HttpClient Http

<h3>Demographics</h3>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var c in dyn.cols)
        {
            <td>@c.Value</td>

        }
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var r in dyn.rows)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var d in r)
            {
                <td>@d.Value</td>

            }
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>

</table>
@code
{
    dynamic dyn;
    //Patient[] patients;

    protected async Task OnInitAsync()
    {

        //patients = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Patient[]>("https://tsrvcis/cis-api/get-patient/by-mrn?format=json");

        var url = "https://tsrvcis/telemedicine-use-case";
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "042a9ff198c04caf99161406f46eaf21|API Testing Script");
        var response = await Http.GetStringAsync(url);

        dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
   }
}
```

The error i am getting:
[image]

Expected result :
 There should be dynamic http table or grid. If there are UI plugin or any other solution that would be great.

Comment: What went wrong using HtpClient?

Comment: got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the following, try it, and come here with the new errors, if any:

```
<h3>Demographics</h3>

@if (dyn == null)
{
   <p>Loading...</p>
} 
else
{ 
      <table class="table table-bordered">
      ....

    </table>
}
```

Comments:

- **You have to ensure that the variable dyn is populated before it is used.**
- I'm not sure I understand why you're using dynamic type
- Is the url OK: https://tsrvcis/telemedicine-use-case
- This is a bearer token right: "042a9ff198c04caf99161406f46eaf21|API Testing Script"
- Are you aware that the HttpClient service you're using is not the actual or real Httplient
- Blazor is using System.Text.Json... So why use Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that you should make some initialization on the start, like

```
dynamic dyn = new {attr1 = new Object(), ...}
```

didn't write C# code for a while (pls fix this) but as I could remember, I got this error solved with initializing of object.
P.S. he uses newtonsoft because of [Blazor WebAPI to Client deserialization exception (PocoJsonSerializerStrategy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56552693/blazor-webapi-to-client-deserialization-exception-pocojsonserializerstrategy/56569478#56569478)